# Use an animated icon in Ionic tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic and am utilising the directive `<ion-tabs></ion-tabs>`

Each tab directive is as standard, eg: 
`<ion-tab title="Sync" icon-off="ion-android-sync" icon-on="ion-android-sync" href="#/tab/sync"><ion-nav-view name="tab-sync"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>`

When the app is busy syncing I'd like that static "ion-android-sync" to animate.

I see there is `<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>` to show spinners but I'm not sure of how to show an animated spinner icon inside a tab - anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So basically you want the spinner in the tab? Could you fiddle what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a definitive solution for you and I am not sure whether this is the best way to do this, but in my opinion the best way to achieve this would be to dissect the `<ion-tab>` element, which would result in the following:

```
<a class="tab-item" href="#/tab/sync">
  <i class="icon"><ion-spinner></ion-spinner></i>
</a>
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a spinner that looks like the `ion-android-sync` icon you used. And of course, more code would be necessary to make this switch between icons, but it is a start.